# Como inicializar N vetores randomicos, onde N é fornecido pelo usuario?

Tags: python

```py
import random

x = int(input("Digite o tamando do cromossoma:  "))
n = int(input("Digite a quantidade de vetores:  "))
saida = []
for _ in range(x):
    saida.append(random.randint(0, 1))
print(saida)
```

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução para esse tipo de situação é usar *list comprehension*:

```py
import random

x = int(input("Digite o tamando do cromossoma:  "))
n = int(input("Digite a quantidade de vetores:  "))
saida = []
for _ in range(x):
    saida.append([random.randint(0,1) for i in range(n)])

for vector in saida:
    print(vector)
```

Retorna `n` vetores de dimensão `x` cada um.